# Python3 + jQuery-File-Upload direct upload s3 | Method not allowed 405

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, jquery-file-upload

I am using Python 3 + Flask to upload video files directly to my S3 storage, but I am getting `Method not allowed 405`

Also the upload must work client side, because the video files have no size limit and will be huge. This would lead to timeouts on the server.

Here are my CORS & Bucket Policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

On server side I use this to sign a request:

```
# Sign request for direct file upload through client for video
@app.route('/sign_s3/<path:file_name_data>/<path:file_type_data>/<up_type>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
@check_confirmed
def sign_s3(file_name_data, file_type_data, up_type):
    if "localhost" in request.url_root:
        if up_type == "profile_vid":
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + get_random_code(5) + "local-profil-video." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]
        else:
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + str(randint(1,100)) + "local-post-video-temp." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]
    else:
        if up_type == "profile_vid":
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + get_random_code(5) + "-profil-video." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]
        else:
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + str(randint(1,100)) + "-post-video-temp." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]

    file_type = file_type_data

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=app.config['MY_AWS_ID'],
        aws_secret_access_key=app.config['MY_AWS_SECRET'],
        region_name='eu-central-1'
    )

    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket = 'mybucket',
    Key = 'videos/' + file_name,
    Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
    Conditions = [
      {"acl": "public-read"},
      {"Content-Type": file_type}
    ],
    ExpiresIn = 3600
    )

    if up_type == "profile_vid":
        if current_user.profile_video != None:
            delete_file_from_aws("videos/", current_user.profile_video)
        setattr(current_user, "profile_video", file_name)
    else:
        print ('post video has been uploaded, no need to delete or set here')

    db_session.commit()

    return json.dumps({'data': presigned_post, 'url': 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/' + 'videos/' + file_name, 'created_file_name' : file_name})
```

Here the clientside Jquery File Uploade code:

```
/************************
 * Upload for video
 *************************/
$('#NEW_fileupload_video').fileupload({
    autoUpload: false,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    disableVideoPreview: false,
    // new
    forceIframeTransport: true, // VERY IMPORTANT.  you will get 405 Method Not Allowed if you don't add this.
    singleFileUploads: true, //default anyway
    // end new
    maxFileSize: 9999999000
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    if ($('#NEW_fileupload_video_files div')[0]) {
        $('#NEW_fileupload_video_files div').remove();
    }   

    var files = data.files || [];
    var nextInQueue = files[0]; //this is a queue, not a list
    if (!nextInQueue) return;

    var fileData = {name: nextInQueue.name, mime: nextInQueue.type, size: nextInQueue.size};

    $.ajax({
        url: "/sign_s3/" + data.files[0].name + "/" + data.files[0].type + "/" + 'profile_vid',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        // I am giving the data through the URL, probably a bad idea
        data: {'file': fileData},
        async: false,
        success: function(res) {
            var response_json_data = res;

            $('input[name="key"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['key']);
            $('input[name="AWSAccessKeyId"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['x-amz-credential']);
            $('input[name="policy"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['policy']);
            $('input[name="signature"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['x-amz-signature']);
            $('input[name="acl"]').val( response_json_data.data.fields['acl']);
            $('input[name="success_action_status"]').val("200");
            $('input[name="Content-Type"]').val(nextInQueue.type);
            //$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').attr('action', response_json_data.url);
            $('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').attr('action', 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/' + response_json_data.created_file_name);
            data.submit();
        }
    }); 
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    console.log("NEW always");
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        console.log("here", file.error);
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#NEW_progress_fileupload_video .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    console.log("done client side video up profile");
}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    console.log("fail", e, data);
})
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="direct_s3_profile_video_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="NEW_fileupload_video" type="file" name="NEW_fileupload_video_files[]" accept="video/*">
 <input type="hidden" name="key">
 <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId">
 <input type="hidden" name="policy">
 <input type="hidden" name="signature">
 <input type="hidden" name="acl">
 <input type="hidden" name="success_action_status">
 <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type">
 <div id="NEW_progress_fileupload_video" class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="NEW_fileupload_video_files" class="files"></div>
 <button type="submit"> Upload </button>
</form>
```

I know its a lot of code. I am really close to understanding how this all works. I think I am missing somewhere something simple. Any ideas are welcome! I would be really thankful.

**EDIT**

Here are also the headers from the DEV console:

GENERAL:

```
Request URL: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/videos/3rBHwNlocal-profil-video.mp4
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 52.219.74.48:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

RESPONSE HEADERS:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: HEAD, DELETE, GET, PUT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 15:18:49 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2: SOME DATA
x-amz-request-id: MY ID
```

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1057282
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5gUAipNLOHxSqN8F
Host: s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Referer: http://localhost:5000/profile
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Have you read the [S3 Boto 3 docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj)?
I'm not sure how the session object works that you have configured but I found it easier to use the S3 resource and `upload_fileobj` to upload to a s3 bucket. You can write your video data in chunks from the POST'ed file without having to temporarily write it to the server

Comment: But this is not a client side upload? Huge files will lead to a timeout on the server, or am I wrong? @Skam

Comment: I see. Can you update your question to include that you want client side upload?  It's not very clear from your post.

Comment: Ofc. thanks for the hint.